# Custom Tag: Attribute without text (boolean value)

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

lets say I have a custom tag with an optional boolean attribute.

That attribute has also a default-value of false.

To use it, the dev would write something like

Is there a way to define that the `="true"`-part is not nesscasary? So that `<xyz:mytag optAttr />` is equal to `<xyz:mytag optAttr="true" />` ?

At least for checkboxes in HTML this is quite common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

JSP custom tags strictly follow XML syntax where this kind of declaration is not allowed (unlike HTML).